# Web-mode + Dust.js, no indentation?

Tags: indentation, microsoft-windows, web-mode, scratch-buffer

If I go to *scratch*, M-x web-mode RET, type in this snippet:

```
<script type="text/x-dust-template">
    {#obj_to_iterate}
    {prop} <----- this should indent
    {/obj_to_iterate}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I see bugs with Dust.js have been solved and I can't be the only one doing simple stuff like this without noticing this indentation behaviour.

Also having problems with the general indentation of HTML, sometimes I get a TAB, sometimes I get two spaces, sometimes one space, who knows what else I can get but it is at least consistent so TAB or spaces are always the same for every line that I indent.

I just want one TAB per identation and properly indented Dust, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem getting `web-mode` to play nice with Django templates. For me the fix was as simple as adding the following to my init file:

```
(setq web-mode-engines-alist
  '(("django"    . "\\.html\\'"))
  )
```

For you, try adding something like:

```
(setq web-mode-engines-alist
  '(("dust"    . "\\.html\\'"))
  )
```

For more details, see the section **Associate an engine** in the `web-mode` [docs](http://web-mode.org/).

Comment: Works on my laptop at home, I have to check at work if this fixes stuff!